# Find related "ordered pairs" in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

Let's say I have a table format that looks exactly like this:

[image: Element Forces - Frames]

I'd like to write a query that locates the maximum station for a given frame and output case (results are grouped by frame & output case) but also return the ordered P (& eventually V2, V3, T, M2 & M3) that would be associated with the maximum station. The desired query is shown below:

[image: Element Forces - Frames, desired query]

I can't for the life of me figure this out.  I've posted a copy of the access database to my google drive: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B9VpkDoFQISJOFcwS2RMSGJ5RVk&usp=sharing

Comment: Please show what you managed to get so far please. Edit you question please, don't put the working in a comment. And as @PM77-1 says - please show simulated output too.

Comment: Or at the very least show your desired output based on your sample data.

Comment: DO NOT post code in comments. Edit your post instead.

Comment: This is either a bog-standard [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem, or an even more standard `ORDER BY` problem (`ORDER BY frame, outputCase` - because `station` appears to be constant per `frame`).  We need better relation between starting sample data and desired results to be able to tell...

Comment: The station isn't constant per frame in the data set, it varies.  The last station is a constant however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select x.*, t.p
  from (select frame, outputcase, max(station) as max_station
          from tbl
         group by frame, outputcase) x
  inner join tbl t
    on x.frame = t.frame
   and x.outputcase = t.outputcase
   and x.max_station = t.station
order by x.frame, x.outputcase;
```

Just as a note to avoid confusion, w/ that second column, t is the table alias, p is the column name.

The subquery, which I've assigned an alias of x, finds the max(station) for each unique combination of (frame, outputcase). That is what you want, but the problem does not stop there, you also want column p. The reason that couldn't be selected in the same query is because you would have had to group by it, and you don't want the max(station) for each combination of (frame, outputcase, p). You want the max(station) for each combination of (frame, outputcase).

Because we couldn't get column p in that first step, we have to join back to the original table using the value we obtained (which I've assigned an alias, max_station), and the obvious join conditions of frame and outputcase. So we join back to the original table on those 3 things, 2 of which are fields on the actual table, one of which was calculated in the subquery (max_station).

Because we've joined back to the original table, we can then select column p from the original table.

Comment: Regardless of whatever else needs doing, you'll need an `ORDER BY` in there somewhere.

Comment: Why I do I need an order by? I am not using an analytic function to solve the problem. I am finding the max for each combination of FRAME and OUTPUTCASE, and then joining back to the original table, using that value.

Comment: Because you have no guarantee that the records will be output in (any) order.  Look at the desired results.  The moment you do a `JOIN` (and even before then, really), the optimizer is going to decide to mess with your desired results.  Repeat after me: "If I do not specify `ORDER BY`, the resulting order is undefined.".  This is especially true if the db is experiencing concurrent access, or is using parallel data access.

Comment: I thought you were saying that the lack of an order by would affect the actual data returned by the sql above, which is not the case. I would assume that he at least knows how to use order by to order the result set in whatever order he wants it in. The answer above mine also does not use order by (outside of the analytic function, which is independent from what you are talking about).

Comment: I'm very new to SQL;  I'm a structural engineer by trade attempting to deal with a wild amount of data output - any amount of detail you can throw into your responses will be appreciated.  I'm working through these solutions now.

Comment: @dkdanielcp I added an explanation of the query

Comment: @dkdanielcp You tagged your post with the wrong database; sql server, which has syntax that is different from Access. In Access you should be able to use "inner join" in place of where I put "join" above (since Access requires that keyword). At that point, it should work.

Comment: @dkdanielcp I updated my response to conform to Access syntax. You may want to change the tag from sql server to Access. They are two different databases.

Comment: @BrianDeMilia - Sorry about the syntax confusion, I've updated the tags to reflect that this post is related to Microsoft Access.  Now the code is stating that the specified field 'frame' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of the SQL statement.  This seems a tad counter intuitive as there is only one column 'frame' in the referenced table.

Comment: @dkdanielcp I left out the table alias for the columns in the order by clause, I just added them (see edit). The reason the alias had to be specified is because those columns appear both in the subquery (x) and the table itself, which we're joining back to (as y). So while they are both the same anyway, it was confused as to whether it should order by that column from x or y.

Answer (score 0):

Takes a bit to return the query, but the result below provides the desired result:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM [Element Forces - Frames] as t1
WHERE t1.Station In (SELECT TOP 1 t2.Station
FROM [Element Forces - Frames] as t2
WHERE t2.Frame = t1.Frame
ORDER BY t2.Station DESC)
ORDER BY t1.Frame ASC, t1.OutputCase ASC;
```

I still want to thank everyone who posted answers.  I'm sure it's just syntax errors on my part that I was struggling with.